python pandas Problem repeating the previous value
is my code
import pandas as pd

columns1 = ['Student ID', 'Course ID', 'Marks']
data1 = [(1, 10, 100), (2, 400, 200), (3, 30, 300), (3, 30, 300), (3, 30, 300), (3, 30, 300), (3, 30, 300), (3, 30, 300)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=columns1)




Student ID
Course ID
Marks




1
10
100


2
400
200


3
30
300


3
30
300


3
30
300


3
30
300


3
30
300


3
30
300



df1['s']  = np.where((df1['Course ID']  > df1['Marks'])  == True, df1['Student ID'],  df1['s'].shift(1)) 
df1




Student ID
Course ID
Marks
s




1
10
100
NaN


2
400
200
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
NaN


3
30
300
NaN


3
30
300
NaN


3
30
300
NaN


3
30
300
NaN



As you can see,
only the information of two rows has changed and the rest are null.
This is the result I expect
because after column 2 condition "df1['Course ID'] > df1['Marks']"
is true



Student ID
Course ID
Marks
s




1
10
100
NaN


2
400
200
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
2


3
30
300
2



Thank you for your help

Hi, welcome to SO. With df1['s'].shift(1) you are shifting a column ('s') that does not yet exist, so there is no way that the second image represents the result of running this exact code. You would receive an error. Please update your post with the expected output (as text, not as an image), and explain what logic you are trying to implement.

It's hard to know what you want, and your code doesn't reproduce your output.

Looks like you want df1['s'] = df1['Student ID'].where(df1['Course ID'] > df1['Marks']).ffill(). Chain .astype('Int64') if you want nullable integers.

If you want to assign the Student ID for rows matching the df1['Course ID'] > df1['Marks'] condition, and for other rows take the previous value, use ffill:
df1['s'] = (df1['Student ID']
            .where(df1['Course ID'] > df1['Marks'])
            .ffill()
            .convert_dtypes() # optional
           )

Output (with a slightly different input):
   Student ID  Course ID  Marks     s
0           1         10    100  <NA>
1           2        400    200     2
2           3         30    300     2
3           3         30    300     2
4           3        400    300     3
5           3         30    300     3
6           3         30    300     3
7           3         30    300     3

If you only want to apply this logic per Student ID, which might make more sense to avoid "leaking" values from one student to another rather use groupby.ffill:
df1['s'] = (df1['Student ID']
            .where(df1['Course ID'] > df1['Marks'])
            .groupby(df1['Student ID']).ffill()
            .convert_dtypes() # optional
           )

Or:
df1['s'] = (df1['Student ID']
            .where(df1['Course ID'].gt(df1['Marks'])
                   .groupby(df1['Student ID']).cummax())
            .convert_dtypes() # optional
           )

Output:
   Student ID  Course ID  Marks     s
0           1         10    100  <NA>
1           2        400    200     2
2           3         30    300  <NA>
3           3         30    300  <NA>
4           3        400    300     3
5           3         30    300     3
6           3         30    300     3
7           3         30    300     3

